# Does std hold a type traits that transforms a list of types and aggregate each transformation value into a single expression?

Tags: c++, templates, std, type-traits

With template specialization, it is possible to code a traits that takes a list of types, apply a transformation on each type that returns a boolean, and then evaluate a final expression that is a `and` on all transformation results:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<template<typename> class TRANSFO, typename ...ARGS>
struct Eval {};

template<template<typename> class TRANSFO, typename T, typename ...ARGS>
struct Eval<TRANSFO, T, ARGS...>
{
    static constexpr bool value = TRANSFO<T>::value and Eval<TRANSFO,ARGS...>::value;
};

template<template<typename> class TRANSFO>
struct Eval<TRANSFO>
{
    static constexpr bool value = true;
};

int main()
{
    static_assert (Eval<std::is_integral,int,long>::value == true);
    static_assert (Eval<std::is_integral,int,float,long>::value == false);
    static_assert (Eval<std::is_integral,float>::value == false);
}
```

**Question** does `std` have already such a thing ? Or is it possible to write it with traits existing in `std` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Question does `std` have already such a thing ? Or is it possible to write it with traits existing in `std` ?

Nothing exactly like this, but the `type_traits` header can indeed remove the boilerplate with [`std::conjunction`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conjunction).

```
template<template<typename> class TRANSFO, typename ...ARGS>
using Eval = std::conjunction<TRANSFO<ARGS>...>;
```

Check it out live at [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:49,endLineNumber:4,positionColumn:49,positionLineNumber:4,selectionStartColumn:49,selectionStartLineNumber:4,startColumn:49,startLineNumber:4),source:%27%23include+%3Ctype_traits%3E%0A%0Atemplate%3Ctemplate%3Ctypename%3E+class+TRANSFO,+typename+...ARGS%3E%0Ausing+Eval+%3D+std::conjunction%3CTRANSFO%3CARGS%3E...%3E%3B%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++static_assert+(Eval%3Cstd::is_integral,int,long%3E::value+%3D%3D+true)%3B%0A++++static_assert+(Eval%3Cstd::is_integral,int,float,long%3E::value+%3D%3D+false)%3B%0A++++static_assert+(Eval%3Cstd::is_integral,float%3E::value+%3D%3D+false)%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:conformance,i:(compilers:!((compilerId:g132,options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B17+-Wall+-Wextra+-pedantic+-Werror+%27),(compilerId:clang1701,options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B17+-Wall+-Wextra+-pedantic+-Werror+%27),(compilerId:vcpp_v19_38_x64,options:%27/std:c%2B%2B17+/W4+/WX+%27)),editorid:1,langId:c%2B%2B,libs:!()),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Conformance+Viewer+(Editor+%231)+3/15%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:50,l:%274%27,m:43.24596774193548,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang1701,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-Wall+-Wextra+-pedantic+-Werror+%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+clang+17.0.1+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27),(h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+clang+17.0.1%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+clang+17.0.1+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:56.75403225806453,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:1,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4).